# Base Internationalization not working

Tags: iphone, ios, text, localization, uibutton

Hello guys I am trying to add localization in my app and I am using storyboards. I added "Base Internationalization"  and it does not appear to be working... For example in my `Locilizible.strings(French)` I have:

[image]

and in my storyboard I have:

[image]

however when I run in the French Simulator I get:

[image]

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
[button setTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Set Subject:", nil) forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

This link may help: [Storyboard/XIB and localization best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846402/storyboard-xib-and-localization-best-practice)

Comment: it's bad practice to send 'nil' for the localization comment field. The localization comment lets you explain exactly how and where this string is used, which your localizers won't know from just reading your strings file.